# Select from multiple tables and build list

Tags: jquery

I am asking this question as a relative newb to Jquery,

### Scenario:

I have two tables:
**GridView1** & **GridView2** which are very similar, the one contains expected values and the other contains actual values.

```
<div style="display: none;">
         <div>
    <table class="EU_DataTable" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="GridView1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tbody><tr>
            <th scope="col">Day of Month</th><th scope="col">Expected Amount</th>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>1</td><td>R34&nbsp;627,00</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>2</td><td>R72&nbsp;474,00</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>3</td><td>R27&nbsp;084,00</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>4</td><td>R9&nbsp;268,00</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
</div>
    </div>
```

*I have shortened it for this question.*

I then have `Jquery` which runs through this table `GridView1` and selects the `first column` as the day and the `second column` as the amount.  I am trying to build a calendar which will say something like `on the 1st: This was expected: R50, This was Paid: R35` (In one list item)

```
var list = $("#thismonth");

            $("#GridView1 tr:has(td)").each(function () {

                var dayforLi = $(this).find("td:eq(0)");
                var amountforLi = $(this).find("td:eq(1)");

                list.append("<li class=cal>" + dayforLi.html() + "<p>Expected: " + amountforLi.html() + "</p></li>");

            });
```

This builds my list for me which I later style as a calendar. The **problem** I am having is accessing the **GridView2** column and adding it into the Jquery that builds my list. I have tried SO many things, which either break my Jquery or add every item from the second table into each list item :(

Hopefully i have explained this in such a way that it is easy for you to know what I am trying to do. If not, please let me know and ill try dig deeper for a better explanation.

Thanks a lot,
Mike

Comment: can you provide fiddle or a screenshot of what you expect to achieve, it's pretty hard to illustrate your need!

Comment: @AminJafari - sure, I will edit the question with Current & Expected output.

Comment: @Mike, I have adde answer with jsfiddle. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this jQuery :

```
var list = $("#thismonth");

$('#GridView1 tr').each(function(index){
  if(index!=0) // this condition to skip tr for header i.e. containing th elements
  {
    var dayforLi = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").html();
    var amountforLi = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").html();

    var actualAmount= $('#GridView2 tr:eq('+index+')').find('td:eq(1)').html();

    list.append("<li class=cal>" + dayforLi + "<p>Expected: " + amountforLi + "</p><p>Actual: " + actualAmount + "</p></li>");
  }
});
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mqEh3/19/)

Comment: Wish I could up vote this the whole day! :D Thank you so much Sir! It does exactly what I wanted.